# Problems with jsoup and select list html tag

Tags: jsoup

I'm new to jsoup and having a bit of trouble with html `<select>` tag.
I need to get value attribute of select list options based on a text they contain.
For example:

```
'<select id="list">
<option value="0">First value</option>
<option value="1">Second value</option>
<option value="2">Third value</option>
</select>'
```

How can I get a value attribute of "Second Value" option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String value = doc.select("#list > option:eq(1)").attr("value");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer HashimR is based on order, not text value.

Answer (score 1):

Proper code basing on option text:

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
 String value = doc.select("#list > option:contains(Second value)").val();
```